# SQL how to insert and left join

Tags: sql

```
name table a            
1.budy                  
2.rendy                
3.rona                  
4.sandi
5.susi

table b
1.budy
2.rendy
3.rona
```

how I can show on table b sandi and susi from table a with sql?

Comment: ask question complete

Comment: You really need to elaborate what you are trying to do here. It is very difficult for someone reading it off of internet to understand your needs.

Comment: There are three answers now, each with a different guess as to what is meant by "show on table b ... from table a". This is a sign that the question is not clear.

Comment: all i need it just query to show name sandi and susi at table b @danish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It:-

```
INSERT INTO tableb
SELECT tablea.id,tablea.name,tableb.id,tableb.name
 FROM tablea
   LEFT JOIN tableb
      ON tablea.name = tableb.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

To test: http://rextester.com/HDZ43705

This will do what you're looking for:

```
select * from A 
except 
select * from B
```

Comment: To further explain this answer. `EXCEPT` works by _selecting_ from `A`, where the data _does not exist_ in `B`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the existence of data in `TableA` using `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` which is not exist in `TableB` and then insert in `TableB`

```
INSERT INTO tableb(name)
SELECT A.name 
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON B.name = A.name
WHERE B.name IS NULL
```

**OR**

```
SELECT A.name 
FROM tableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableB B WHERE B.name = A.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most optimized solution, but guess it will work:

```
SELECT name 
FROM TableB

UNION

SELECT name 
FROM TableA
```

Will return a DISTINCT version of the data in both tables, if that was what you were looking for (a joined view of the tables).

If you only want to show the names in A that are not in B, then something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM TableA WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM TableB)
```

I think this is essentially the same soution that DEEPAK suggested, only his was more compact and modern.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

INSERT INTO tableb

SELECT tablea.id,tablea.name FROM dbo.tablea

LEFT JOIN dbo.tableb

ON tablea.id=tableb.id

WHERE tableb.id is null